VGA - Changing 25MHz to Higher Frequency
I've been using a 25MHz clock for quite some time to generate a VGA signal (still a novice when it comes to electronics):
640x480 resolution, 800 clocks per line,
160 clocks of horizontal porch,
hsync for clocks < 15 and greater than 111;
524 lines, vertical porch starting at line 480, vsync between lines 491 and 493
For the current project I'm working on, I wanted to try changing the 25MHz clock to 28MHz.
How do the porch/hsync and vsync timings change when a different clock is used?

I'm not sure it will work at all; there's some leniency in the timings but changing the clock by that much might necessitate changing the resolution or framerate. At your current clock and framerate you have one clock per pixel for 640×480; at 28 MHz you'll have a non-integer number of clocks per pixel.

@Hearth yeah it turns into a mess. At the moment the monitor cannot seem to figure out where the left of the display is - the monitor seems to think that it's way to the far left, way past anywhere that the horizontal adjustment can show. Maybe there are only a set of specific frequencies that VGA monitors can accept?

I may be able to use 720x400.. This page lists this resolution at 28MHz http://martin.hinner.info/vga/timing.html

@Hearth At 25 MHz you have 640 integer pixels per line with total of 800 clocks per line. At 28 MHz you have 720 integer pixels per line with total of 900 pixels per line. There are no non-integer number of pixels here.

@Justme I don't suppose you would know the vertical porch/pixel/line count for a 720x400 display at 28MHz? I'm missing 50 lines at the moment. It's bound to be caused by wrong values I'm using for vsync

@SparkyNZ The timings  are identical for all 70Hz formats. 449 lines total. The 400-line format has 12 lines before sync, 2 lines sync, 35 lines sync. The 28 MHz vs 25 MHz clock does not affect it. However the sync polarities must be correct to tell the monitor to use 400 or 350 or 480 line scan speeds.

@Justme Thanks for that. I was using 400-11-2-37. I'll change it to 400-12-2-35 as you suggest. There may be some bugs in my Verilog. It seemed to work fine in 640x480 but maybe the monitor just doesn't like it. It's an old Dell 19" monitor.. not sure if I have anything else to try 720x400 resolution on it, but probably makes sense to try that first.

@SparkyNZ If I am not mistaken there was only 448 lines and  sync started one line later. It should not matter. You might be missing lines if your monitor thinks you want it to be in 350-line mode.

@Justme I meant there would be a non-integer number of clocks per line if you tried to keep the 640×480 resolution. You would have to change either resolution or framerate to use a 28 MHz clock.

@Hearth Yes and in standard analog VGA, you must keep same horizontal sync. And you can just have 640 narrower pixels in smaller area. Or 720 pixels in same area. I guess you count that as resolution change as the amount of horizontal total changes. 4xfc PAL does have non-integer sampling clocks per line but it's not really important.

@Justme are there any other screen resolutions that should work with a 28MHz pixel clock? After battling for hours, I tried a different monitor (security cam monitor) and it displays my 720x400 resolution perfectly. Would it be possible to run 720x480 for example?

@Justme Both the Dell and security cam like my 720x480 resolution at 28MHz! I think I have a winner

@SparkyNZ Like I said the 400-line formats are 70 Hz which a modern monitors don't support. If you send a 31 kHz 480-line format in analog, no device can know what pixel clock was used and how many pixels it has.

On an original VGA card and monitor, the 25.175 MHz clock was usually used for 640 and 320 pixel wide formats, because these have 800 clocks per line. The amount of lines determine the vertical frequency, and the polarity of the sync signals set the monitor to a correct mode to scan the screen with either 400, 350 or 480 visible lines.
The 28.322 MHz clock was usualy used for the text mode which has 720 visible pixels per line, or 900 clocks per line. The normal text mode characters were 9 clocks wide but in other modes there are 8 clocks wide, and therefore evrrything is scaled by 9/8, like 28.322/25.175 MHz clock.
So technically, if you take the parameters of 640 pixel format, all numbers should be multiples of character clocks of 8, and scale everything by 9/8 you should have equal timing in 28.322 MHz units.
This still makes the horizontal freqyency almost identical between 640 and 720 wide formats, and the reason is that the VGA monitor supported only one horizontal rate of around 31.47 kHz.
Some programs (e.g. games) supported setting non-standard graphics modes and for example you could reprogram a 360 pixel wide graphics mode by switching to 28 MHz clock and writing the horizontal parameters. Most games that modified the timings however just switched to 320x240 mode which offers a square pixel aspect ratio with the expense of frame rate dropping to 60 Hz and screen being a bit more flickery.
However, these tricks work well with an analog monitor. If you have a digital screen, it might not accept custom formats, many modern displays might not even support the standard VGA 720x400 text mode any more, and they might complain about custom formats not being optimal or supported.
I also managed to find register dumps of different modes. Both the text mode, 320-wide and 640-wide modes used the exact same parameters in character clocks, which means they are 8 pixels at 25 MHz or 9 pixels at 28 MHz. The only difference was that the text mode had delayed the hsync pulse by 1 character clock, but that might just be due to compensating intenal processing delay so it's just to move the text one character cell left.
Also your original 640x480 signal had off-by-one error - it has 800 total pixels per line and 525 total lines per frame, not 524.
